# $(\sum_j a_j |b_j|)^2 \leq \sum_j a_j |b_j|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to prove this relation $(\sum_j a_j |b_j|)^2 \leq \sum_j a_j |b_j|^2$, where $b_j$ is a vector for every $j$ and $0<a_j<1$. The material which I am referring hints at the use of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Any help or hint is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if you take $j=2$, $|b_1|= |b_2|=1$ and $a_1=a_2=\frac{2}{3}$ don't you get $(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3})^2 \leq (\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3})$ which is clearly false?

Comment: If $\sum a_j = 1$, the stated inequality is true. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

C-S states that
$(\sum u_iv_i)^2
\le \sum u_i^2\sum v_i^2
$.

You want to show that
$(\sum_j a_j |b_j|)^2 
\leq \sum_j a_j |b_j|^2
$.

C-S immediately gives
$(\sum_j a_j |b_j|)^2 
\leq (\sum_j a_j^2)(\sum_j |b_j|^2)
$,
but that is not what we want.

We want $a_j$ and $|b_j|^2$ on the right.
To do that,
we need
$\sqrt{a_j}$ and $|b_j|$
on the left.

Let's try writing
$a_j |b_j|
=\sqrt{a_j}(\sqrt{a_j}|b_j|)
$.
C-S then gives
$(\sum_j a_j |b_j|)^2 
=(\sum \sqrt{a_j}(\sqrt{a_j}|b_j|))^2
\le (\sum a_j)(\sum a_j |b_j|^2) 
$.

This is almost what you want.
However,
the additional
$\sum a_j$
leads me to suspect
that perhaps the
stated inequality is incorrect.

To test,
set all
$a_j = |b_j| = 1$.
(You can set $a_j = 1-\epsilon$
and the following conclusion
will still be correct.

The inequality then becomes,
if there are $n$ items,
$n^2 \le n$,
which is clearly not true.

Therefore,
I believe that the desired inequality is

$(\sum_j a_j |b_j|)^2 
\le (\sum a_j)(\sum a_j |b_j|^2) 
$.

Note that
if
$\sum a_j = 1$,
you get the stated inequality.

Comment: Thanks a million. Your assumption $\sum_j a_j=1$ is correct. It was my mistake that I didn't mention it earlier. Please forgive me.

Comment: So why didn't you accept my answer?